# How to use custom sub-domain name with my Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I need to use a domain like `http://mycompany.inventory.com` with my site. Where can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using multisite, you can enable subdomain with the following setting in wp-config: read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

```
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
```

or try wordpress mu [domain mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).
tutorial can be found here: http://www.wpwebhost.com/2009/09/using-multiple-domains-with-wordpress-mu/